# Why won't this work sometimes only on particular record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I made a transaction that calculates how many members current_user's communities own, and how many members each community has.

If other registered user press on "Join" at the particular community.
The user will be the member of the community, and the community's owner gains 1 point.

Of course, it does opposite action when the user press "quit" from the community.

I coded like this, and it was working fine so far.
However, I've found just one community doesn't accept this transaction.
Indeed, it switches flag but without these calculation and count transaction.
So the number of Point, and The number of members won't be changed:(
It almost looks like the record is locked!

Why does this happen? Just one record!!

### controller

```
    if current_user.voted_up_on? @community
        current_user.dislikes @community
        
        #Calculate the points of the community's owner
        if @community.user
            @user = User.find(@community.user_id)
            @user.profile.total_point = Community.sum(:cached_votes_up, :conditions => ["user_id = ?", @user]) + @user.profile.bonus_point
            @user.profile.next_level = next_level_set(@user)
            @user.save
        end
        
        #count how many members the community has.
        @users =  User.where(:id => @community.likes.map(&:voter_id))
        @community.cached_votes_up = @users.count           
        @community.save
        
        
    else
        current_user.likes @community
        
        #Calculate the points of the community's owner
        if @community.user
            @user = User.find(@community.user_id)
            @user.profile.total_point = Community.sum(:cached_votes_up, :conditions => ["user_id = ?", @user]) + @user.profile.bonus_point
            @user.profile.next_level = next_level_set(@user)
            @user.save
        end
        
        #count how many members the community has.
        @users =  User.where(:id => @community.likes.map(&:voter_id))
        @community.cached_votes_up = @users.count           
        @community.save
                    
        
    end
```

Comment: Can you describe the record that you see this behavior with? How does it differ from other records?

Comment: @StuartM I'm at the page `/community/18` in this page, `Members: 54` and `Owner: John(136)` are shown. This should be increased by 1 when a user joined this community(id:18). If I join the other community, it gets increaed by 1, and it gets deceased by 1 if quit. However the same thing won't happen. It does nothing only on this community(18)

Comment: When you are calling `@community.save`, is `@community` possibly failing to save successfully? You don't appear to be checking its return values, so could it be returning `false`, perhaps from validation errors?

Comment: @StuartM Is the any easy way to check that?

Comment: One way would be to log it, such as `logger.debug "@community.save: #{@community.save}"`

Comment: @StuartM Thanks. one thing I'm suspecting about is Logical deletion. The user will be deleted by logical deletion however, votes record remains. So this could be messing up. Is it possible to fetch only the active user? `@users =  User.where(:id => @community.likes.map(&:voter_id))` this code seems fetching all votes records.

Comment: lol I found one thing. I was trying to edit and update the record but I've got validation error for having the tags more than maximum. I removed it and updated. After that, everything is solved. This is so weird....

Comment: It's fetching multiple users since the `map` function will return an array, so the underlying SQL clause will have `id IN (...list of IDs...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess that you are attempting to call `save` on `@community` but it is failing to save for some reason, perhaps a validation error. I recommend checking the result of `@community.save`, and if it is `false`, check `@community.errors` for the validation errors. Also see the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#working-with-validation-errors) on the subject.